# HTML5 Article or Main Element — Should it always be used?

Tags: html, sections

In a simple HTML5 document, you might have something like the following:

```
header
nav
article
footer
```

The definition of an article implies that it wraps the main self-contained content.

The question is: should all pages contain an article element. This includes pages with only a contact form, for example.

Thanks

Comment: There's plenty of examples in the HTML5 spec of pages without article elements. [Like this one: http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#example-91d58dcd](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#example-91d58dcd)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That same page also contained the point I was looking for. (See my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

According to [HTML 5.1: 4.3. Sections: The article element](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-article-element), the `article` element can be implied:

> When the main content of the page (i.e., excluding footers, headers, navigation blocks, and sidebars) is all one single self-contained composition, that content may be marked with an article, but it is technically redundant in that case (since it’s self-evident that the page is a single composition, as it is a single document).

That would suggest that it’s OK either way.

I think marking it up in an article still has the benefit of being clearer and providing an appropriate container for CSS. However, it is clearly not required.